# $anchorScroll only after ng-view load, not before

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to autoscroll on top of a page after i load new content in my ng-view div.

So i implemented $anchorScroll, and call a function to jump on top of a page:

```
"use strict";

angular.module("someApp")
  .controller("ScrollCtrl", function($scope, $location, $anchorScroll) {
    $scope.scrollTo = function(id) {
      $location.hash(id);
      $anchorScroll();
    }
  });
```

When i click the "next" button, i want to first load the new page, and then jump on top. But, of corse, i click the "a-tag" and then it immediatly jumps to my anchor:

```
 <a ng-href="#/ropute/to/new/content" ng-click="scrollTo('question_content')" >
```

**How can i avoid this?**

Comment: Here which is the next button?. The same anchor tag??

Comment: The next button is inside the shown a-tag. The ng-href is in my case a model which is dynamically changed through the scope. This doesn't matter here.

Comment: I'm not strong in angularjs and this is my doubt. If button inside the a-tag then how click event will get to button?

Comment: This isn't the question. Button working, Anchor-Working, Routing-Working... i just want to prevent the jumping to the top before the next page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is to navigate to `/route/to/new/content` and then automatically scroll down to the `question_content` element?

In that case, there's two problems with your current approach. The first is that your `ng-click` will fire before the new view is loaded and visible, so it won't scroll to the element. The second is that Angular already uses the url hash to store the current location (unless you call `html5Mode()` on the `$locationProvider`). So setting the location hash to `question_content` will not scroll to an element with that id, it will tell Angular to try and load the route for `question_content`, which I assume you don't have.

So I'd change your HTML to something like:

```
<a ng-href="#/route/to/new/content?scroll_to=question_content">
```

And then set up a directive on your `body` element (or the same element your `ng-view` is on) which listens to the `$viewContentLoaded` event, looks for the `scroll_to` location search param, looks up that element, calculates it's top offset (through jQuery) and scrolls the page to it.